# Is quotient group $\frac{D_{20}}{D_{20}^{'}}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{4}}$ or to $\mathbb{Z_{2}}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $D_{20}=\{a,b:a^{10}=e,b^{2}=e,(ba)^{2}=e\}$ be the dihedral group of order $20$ and $D_{20}'$ be its commutator subgroup which is cyclic group of order $5.$ So clearly $\frac{D_{20}}{D_{20}^{'}}$ is an abelian group of order $4.$ My question: is $\frac{D_{20}}{D_{20}^{'}}\cong\mathbb{Z_{4}}$ OR  $\frac{D_{20}}{D_{20}^{'}}\cong\mathbb{Z_{2}}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}?$ According to me its non cyclic group of order $4$ as group has no element of order $4$ but don't know how exactly. Please give me some suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since $D_{20}$ has no element of order a multiple of 4, and since going to a quotient group can't increase the order, the quotient group has no element of order 4.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order that your question is more easily accessible.

Comment: Thanks.............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is every square of every element in $D_{20}$ within $D_{20}'$?
Each element is a rotation or a reflection so that's not hard to determine.

If so, then each element of the quotient group has order $1$ or $2$ and
it is isomorphic to $Z_2\times Z_2$.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown        So it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown      Can i say as: Since order of commutator subgroup is $5$ so quotient group has an element or order $4$ if group has an element of order $20.$ Which is not possible??

Comment: There is a group of order $20$ with no element of order $20$ but with $G/G'\cong Z_4$. @neelkanth